# Meaning of C++/pthread/join error message "what(): Invalid argument"

Tags: c++, pthreads

It is a part of a larger application, a simple timer thread, which works correctly before an attempt to finish it:

```
boost::asio::io_service io_service;
shared_ptr<thread> loop;
// it is not initialised here, just shows the idea
boost::asio::deadline_timer timer(io_service, interval);

void Timer::spin() {
    loop = make_shared<thread>(&Timer::run, this);
}
void Timer::unspin() {
    io_service.stop();
    loop.get()->join();
}
void run() {
   timer.async_wait(bind(&Timer::callbackWrapper, this, _1));
   // restart
   io_service.run();    
}
```

The thread created in `spin` is in theory terminated and joined in `unspin()`. In case when the application ends with `join()` commented out, there in an error message

```
terminate called without an active exception
```

which, if I "decrypted" it well, means "main thread finished when some other threads are still running" (I do not know the C++ lingo.)

If, in turn, `unspin()` is called, the following *spotty* error message may show:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::system_error'
  what():  Invalid argument
```

which is most probably thrown by `thread.join()`. The problem is, I searched around Stackexchange, but could not explain the other message. I realise that the problem can be outside the small fragment of code (the application is rather large, so I do not include it). But even if it is so, I would just ask for the meaning of the second error message and its *possible* causes.

Comment: No, "if decrypted" it means "`std::thread`'s destructor was called while the execution thread was still running".

Comment: I can't quite follow this. Can you show us the actual problematic code? It appears that you've posted working code then vaguely described two ways of breaking it but it would be better if you presented a [MCVE] that clearly shows the problem and asks a question about it.

Comment: Yes I realise it, see the last paragraph. But the error message is spotty, the code above can also work well by itself. I would just want to know the meaning of the message, I am not a C++ library writer, I do not know the lingo.

Comment: @Sam Varshavchik, thanks for the hint, I am analysing it now. I will post later.

Comment: You should reset the shared_ptr in `unspin` and detect a call to `unspin` without a prior call to `spin`.

Comment: @Sam, how can `std::thread`'s destructor be called within a method of `Timer`, if `shared_ptr<thread> loop` is a field of `Timer`, and I do not nullify the pointer in any way?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz, resetting it causes `terminate called without an active exception`. By the way, why should I do this?

Comment: @scriptfoo Because if you don't, two consecutive calls to `unspin` will cause the very problem you're describing. Same with two consecutive calls to `spin`. I hope your real code has checks for these kinds of things because if not this code will be impossible to debug. If code calls `spin` and then calls `spin` again without calling `unspin`, what happens to the thread created in the first call to `spin`?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Yes, there are two consecutive calls to `unspin`, an effect of another bug. So the error is an effect of calling join() twice. Thanks David!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In my particular case, the exception was thrown because the thread had already been joined. Check [joinable](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/join) before joining.

Answer (score 2):

The possible causes for something to throw `std::system_error` (with `EINVAL`, as here, or with some other value) are numerous.

You could either:

1. Google for instances of `std::system_error` on cppreference.com, or
2. Instruct your debugger to break on throw, then you can see exactly what's caused an exception to be thrown — then go to the documentation for that thing and read why it would throw.

These messages aren't cryptic *per se*, they're just indirect oweing to the way the whole C++ ecosystem works. Could it have been designed to call some specific "terminate" function solely reserved for the case where you forget to join a thread? Sure.

But that would be really unwieldy, bulking up the size of the runtime module, for not really any gain. As you write more code you will gain experience and start just remembering or "feeling" what sort of things can cause what sort of problems. Anything about `std::system_error` or `std::terminate` in multi-threaded code is *almost certainly* something to do with improper handling of said threads. You just get to know that after a while.

In this case you can memorise the two following explanations:

> terminate called without an active exception

[Something](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/~thread) called `std::terminate` directly. Again, you can search for utterances of this in library documentation and find out possible causes that relate to your code.

> terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::system_error'

[An exception was thrown](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/join), but you have no `try`/`catch` in your program that caught it, so `std::terminate` was invoked by the exceptions system. Again, you can research what features you're using can throw `std::system_error`, and also consider adding some exception safety to your code while you're at it.

Comment: Yes, I guess they are not cryptic if you know the C++ lingo. But I don't, and my debugger introduces an "error of measurement", that is, the error message is probably an effect of some spotty race condition.

Comment: @scriptfoo Naturally, anything is cryptic before you know what it means, but I mean in the context of C++ it's actually a sensible output and you'll realise that when you do know what it means ;) And, yes, using the debugger isn't foolproof but it's always a good start, and in this case will point you to the problematic line of code reliably within seconds (then you confirm with documentation). Don't assume that it won't be able to help you until you find that it can't.

Answer (score 1):

This code, in its current form, cannot reasonably be debugged. This is because it has interface rules (such as not calling `spin` twice in a row) that are not detected by the code. This makes the code very hard to test, debug, and maintain.

It can even make the code hard to understand because these requirements probably aren't documented anywhere in code or in text. For the future:

1. Make your code detect these kinds of violations of its interface requirements so that you can easily find and fix them. This is easy here. The `unspin` function can `reset` the `shared_ptr`. The `spin` function can check that the `shared_ptr` is unseated.
2. Make unit tests that test all the correct and incorrect interface accesses so you can debug this code on its own and also make sure the detection of incorrect access patterns works right. One of the unit tests should call `spin` twice in a row and make sure it returns the right error or throws the right exception. This also serves as code that documents what will and won't work with the interface to the class.
3. If you encounter a problem you can't fix, the code and unit test can then stand alone to show the issue, and you'll know exactly what aspect of the code is failing.

This also makes the code maintainable. If someone wants to re-implement this code, add a feature, or optimize it, they have the unit test to make sure they didn't break any of its behavior that other code is expected to rely on.